# normality in conjugate subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $K$ and $gKg^{-1}$ be conjugate subgroups of $G$ (for some $g \in G$), and suppose that some subgroup $H \subseteq G$ is contained in both $K$ and $gKg^{-1}$. If $H$ is normal in $K$, must it also be normal in $gKg^{-1}$?

Comment: The question really could use more context.

Comment: @RobertShore What sort of context would you like? This is a question that arose in my research (although I would certainly not call it a research-level question -- I'm not a group theorist).

Comment: My immediate reaction to this is what possible reason could you have for thinking it might be true?

Comment: @DerekHolt My fault, I should have phrased this less opaquely: I expected this to be false, and was looking for a counterexample. (Perhaps Robert would also have appreciated this.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Let $G=S_5$, let $K$ be the subgroup generated by the copy of $S_3$ that fixes $4$ and $5$, and $(45)$, let $H$ be the subgroup $\{\mathrm{id},(45)\}$; and let $g=(14)(25)$.

The subgroup $K$ consists of the elements of $S_5$ that preserve the partition $\{ \{1,2,3\},\{4,5\}\}$. Note that $H$ is normal, because it is central in $K$.

On the other hand, $gKg^{-1}$ consists of the elements of $S_5$ that preserve the partition $\{\{3,4,5\},\{1,2\}\}$. This also contains $H$, but $H$ is no longer central. In fact, $H$ is not normal, since $(345)(45)(354)=(35)\notin H$, even though $(345)\in gKg^{-1}$.

The image of $H$ in $gKg^{-1}$ is of course normal in $gKg^{-1}$, but it is $\{\mathrm{id},(12)\}$ not $H$ itself.

Comment: Great! Thanks for this explicit counterexample.